# How to play translate transform in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a button that I want to translate horizontally, so I use the storyboard like this:

```
 <Button>
<Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Studio" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" From="0" To="5000" Duration="0:0:2">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
</Button.Triggers>
 </Button>
```

but nothing happens

Comment: What is your goal?  You want to turn the button horizontally on clicking?

Comment: You want to grow or spin?

Comment: Just a simple move from right to left with some easing effect at the begining and end of the animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing happens because there is no `TranslateTransform` in the Button's `RenderTransform`.

Just add one, and remove the `Storyboard.TargetName` from the DoubleAnimation :

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform/>
    </Button.RenderTransform>
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.X"
                        To="5000" Duration="0:0:2">
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```